# Push data inside nested array , mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Please I know its **duplicate**, but I dont know why my code is not working

```
exports.addTechnologyPost = function(req, res){


     console.log(req.params.name);
     var query = {
        name: 'testName',
        version: 'testVer',
        note: 'testNote',
        status: true
     };
     console.log( query );
     Project.findOneAndUpdate(
        { name: req.params.name },
        { $push : {"technologies.$.server" : query }  },  {  upsert: true, new: true },   
        function(err, project) {

        })


 }
```

**My Schema**

```
..........
technologies:{
    server:[{
        name: String,
        version: Number,
        note: String,
        status: Boolean
    }]
  }
..........
```

If its correct or any syntax error ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the `$` in the push object key?

```
Project.findOneAndUpdate(
        { name: req.params.name },
        { $push : {"technologies.server" : query }  },  {  upsert: true, new: true },   
        function(err, project) {

        })
```

Comment: Fixed, I was pushing 'version' data as a string but it should be number